# can i sendBroadcast from class extend AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, interface, broadcastreceiver

I have a class that extends the AsyncTask.

When the doing background task done, in post executed i get the static properties of other class to equal the result of doing background, n I WANT TO BROADCAST IT OUT SO THAT the on receiver in other class will be update interface

here the code of the onPostExecuted

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    Log.d(tag, "post executed "+result);
    // do sth here

    if (result != null){
        result = result.trim();
        String temp_result[];
        if ( result.contains("|") ){
            temp_result = result.split("\\|");
            MyGPS.location_info = temp_result[1];//
            Log.d(result, "contains | : "+MyGPS.location_info);
        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("300 OK")){
            Log.d(result, "in 300 OK BUT UNKNOWN : "+ result);
            MyGPS.location_info = "Unknown";
        }else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("400 ERROR"))
            Log.d(result, "400 ERROR : "+ result);
        else Log.d(result, "else : "+ result);

        //assemble data bundle to be broadcasted
        //myFilteredResponseThread = new Intent(GPS_FILTER);
        myFilteredResponseThread.putExtra("location_info_post", 

MyGPS.location_info);
                    // CAN"T USE SEND BROADCAST METHOD ?


        //myFilteredResponseThread.
        //Log.e(">>GPS_Service<<", "location_info"+MyGPS.location_info);
    }   
}
```

after that i can't write sendBroadcast method , it is undefined whY?

Comment: may be you are not passing activity context to this class that extends AsyncTask. If you are passing activity context then use context.sendbroadcat(intent)

Comment: i call this thread AysnctTask from my inner-class GPSListener implements LocationListener and this inner class is in a class extends service, so how can i pass context to my AsyncTask ? thx

Answer (score 0):

If I understood u correctly following is the solution.

```
class MyService extends Service{

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

       class GPSListener implements LocationListener{
        public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // you can get context as follow
            MyService.this.getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("Hi"));
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

       }
```

}

Comment: Thx boy, i start confuse since the MyService.this.getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent("Hi"));

here y have new Intent("Hi") cuz i 1 2 send context to my AsyncTask class, sorry since i'm a newbie